# Firebase audiences - unable to use UserID filter

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

Until very recently we have been able to create audiences using the User ID filter as below.

[image: Audience by user id]

We use the setUserId function in our code as shown below. I have confirmed this is still being called.

```
firebaseAnalytics?.apply {
    setUserId("some id")
    // other user properties

}
```

Now when we go to create an audience with the user id we cannot pick user id as an option. We also can't duplicate our old audiences as all of them seem to be unsupported now with the following error `Your audience contains one or more unsupported concepts`.

We are using `com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx:20.1.0` on Android.

I cannot see anything in the release notes to suggest something has changed in firebase.

Comment: Yes we are experiencing the same issue. I looked into the release notes for analytics but there is not mentioned anything about it.

Comment: I'm also getting the same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Any updates on it?